# Mono - crystal reports runtime version not loading

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports, mono

I am building a crystal reports page in asp.net to publish to my web server running Apache.  I have installed Mono and confirmed it to be working, but when I attempt to open my crystal report now, I am stuck at this error.  When I compile in x86 or AnyCPU in VS19, I can test it perfectly fine, but breaks when moved to production in my web server.

`CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.LoadSaveReportException`

An error has occurred while attempting to load the Crystal Reports runtime. Either the Crystal Reports registry key permissions are insufficient, or the Crystal Reports runtime is not installed correctly. Please install the appropriate Crystal Reports redistributable (CRRedist*.msi) containing the correct version of the Crystal Reports runtime (x86, x64, or Itanium) required.  Please go to http://www.businessobjects.com/support for more information

Description: HTTP 500.Error processing request.

Details: Non-web exception. Exception origin (name of application or object): CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.

Exception stack trace:

`at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.CheckForCrystalReportsRuntime () [0x00086] in <e95cc768b91f413da55e0439ed43ae71>:0`

`at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument..cctor () [0x0003f] in <e95cc768b91f413da55e0439ed43ae71>:0`

Comment: "Please go to http://www.businessobjects.com/support for more information" is the key here. Talk to Crystal Reports' vendor and they probably can tell you if Mono and Apache are supported (very likely not).

Comment: Somewhere in the background, Crystal Reports uses good old ActiveX - the fact that you are using a portable Assembly reference doesn't change that. This means that you need MS Windows to get this to work. So I would guess that Mono or Apache isn't the problem here - indeed you could probably run your solution on Mono with Apache on a Windows server, but not a Linux one, although if you have a Windows server, you'd probably use IIS and dotnetFramework instead.